# MATLAB: Conversion to char from cell is not possible

Tags: matlab, variables, data-structures

So I've got a struct, settings, which contains three fields, averageValue, heightLabels and heights.

settings.averageValue = 7.5121 7.2742 7.4602
settings.heights = 105.1000 105.2000 105.3000

I'm looping through these with the following code:

```
for m = 1:length(settings.averageValue)
    settings.heightLabels(m) = {sprintf{'%.1f %s', settings.heights(m), 'm')};
end
```

However, I get the error "Conversion to char from cell is not possible.". Any ideas?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "as if it were a variable"? What is the difference you'd like to remove?

Comment: I think they're talking about how if they create a variable called `counter`, then the input `counter` will give output `counter = 1`, whereas the input `settings.counter` will give the output `ans = 1`. @user2540113 what the output says won't make a difference. You can just save the value into another variable. Like this: `counter = settings.counter`.

Comment: The name shown by MATLAB when you type the expression you want to see isn't important.  settings.counter is exactly what you want.  If you want to print the name next to the value in some automated way, explain that problem separately...

Comment: `settings = struct('counter', counter);`

Comment: Dan455 has it. I figured using a struct to store all variables would be easier for passing the variables between files and functions. That's why I don't want to save the value into another variable, I want to edit the value where it is, in the struct.

What makes me confused is the fact that using the struct instead of separate variables gives me a different result.

Comment: So is your problem resolved or are you still unsure how to do something?

Comment: How did you create the variables in the first place?

Comment: I think you're good to go.  The only "different result" you're getting is the text printed by MATLAB to label the output.  This doesn't affect your computation.

Comment: Alright thanks guys, you made me realize the output didn't matter. I narrowed it down to a loop which seems to cause problems. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys I figured it out. It was a datatype question; my struct field was supposed to be a cell but it was a string. Rather embarrassing.

I resolved the problem with the following code when creating the struct fields:

```
settings.averageValue = {};
settings.heightLabels = {};
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So, you've finally achieved what you set out to? Sweet!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I get your question now. Let's say you have variables A,B,C,D which you want to club together in a struct variable. Here's how you do it:

```
settings.A = A;
settings.B = B;
settings.C = C;
settings.D = D;
```

settings is a struct variable now, and if you want to access A, you refer to it as:

```
disp(settings.A) %display A
settings.A = 10; %edit A
newA = settings.A; %assign A to a new variable
```

Pass settings to a function, do whatever.

Comment: Not exactly. What I want to do is move a bunch of variables into a struct, in order to smoothly pass it between functions and files. I also want to be able to edit the struct values, but keep them in the struct without saving them to separate variables. Does this make sence?

Comment: I'm sorry, my question was misleading because of my lack of MATLAB experience. I have updated my question.